# Mysqli rollback is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, transactions, mysqli

I have a MySQL db and I am using `mysqli`.

for some reason I can't get transactions to work properly. If I call `$mysqli->rollback()`, it does not roll back.

example code:

```
$mysqli->autocommit(false);

$sql = "INSERT INTO myTable (name , color) VALUES ('Dan' , 'red')";

$mysqli->query($sql);

$mysqli->rollback();
```

Tthe result is that another row is added to myTable. Can anyone think of a reason why?

Comment: Using a MyISAM table instead of InnoDB?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

are you using myIsam or innodb?? becouse it only works for innodb as far as i know

Comment: how do I check? 
this is a local server, i use XAMPP

Comment: SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE `Name` = 'your_table_name'; and check col engine

Comment: ow... I think it is MyISAM.
what does that mean? should I somehow change it to innodb?

Comment: ALTER TABLE your_table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;

Comment: Thanks!
one more thing, is there a reason not to user InnoDB?

Comment: every engine has its advantages and disadvantages, so it depends on your needs

Comment: well... I need to use transactions... so I guess there is no chois but to use InnoDB :)