# rollback if one of multple inserts fails using prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, transactions

I have a form script that inserts data in multiple tables. But if one fails it has to revert everything back. I've been looking for this but I didn't find a question that uses multiple (mysqli) prepared statements and rollback.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(/* connection details */);
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);

// rollback should revert here
$mysqli->begin_transaction();

if ($stmt_one = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO main_table (one, two, three) VALUES (?, ?, ?)')) {
    $stmt_one->bind_param('sss', $one, $two, $three);
    $stmt_one->execute();

    $id = (int) $mysqli->insert_id;

    if ($stmt_two = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO sub_table_one (id, four) VALUES (?, ?)')) {
        $stmt_two->bind_param('is', $id, $four);
        $stmt_two->execute();
    }

    if ($stmt_three = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO sub_table_two (id, five) VALUES (?, ?)')) {
        $stmt_three->bind_param('is', $id, $five);
        $stmt_three->execute();
    }
}

if ($mysqli->commit()) {
    // everything ok
    header('Location: /');
} else {
    // something went wrong, we have to rollback
    $mysqli->rollback();
    // and display the error message
    echo $stmt_one->error;
    echo $stmt_two->error;
    echo $stmt_three->error;
}
```

I'm not sure about this, can I do something like that? Or do I have to check every `$stmt_*` for errors?

---

**UPDATE**

**(The problem was that I was using DB Engine MyISAM instead of InnoDB)**

I've upgraded to PHP 7 and now rollback is not working. I've tried the following:

```
if (!$mysqli->rollback()) $log .= 'no rollback :(';
```

But I don't see that message in my log...

My current code looks like:

```
public function Upload() {

    try {

        // rollback should revert here
        $mysqli->begin_transaction();

        // multiple prepared statements

        if ($mysqli->commit()) {
            $exit = $log;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Transaction commit failed. Property ID: ' . $this->id);
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        try {

            $test = $this->owner['id'] ? 'property' : ($this->applicant ? 'demand' : 'Fatal Error: PropertyFromInput() contact error (no owner, no applicant)');

            $log = 'Rolling back new ' . $test . ' upload' . "\n";

            if (!$mysqli->rollback()) $log .= 'no rollback...' . "\n";

            if ($test == 'property') $log .= $this->cleanup_prop() ? 'property successfully cleaned up' . "\n" : 'error while cleaning up property' . "\n";

            $err_msg = $e->getMessage();

        } catch (Exception $f) {

            $err_msg .= $f->getMessage();

        }

        $usr_msg = $upload_err ? $err_msg : 'Se ha producido un error. Por favor contacte con un administrador.';

        $log .= 'User triggered an error while uploading a new ' . $test . ".\n" . 'Error message: ' . $err_msg;

        $exit = array($log, $usr_msg);

    }

    $mysqli->autocommit(TRUE);

    return $exit;
}
```

My log looks like:

```
Logging new property upload...

Rolling back new property upload
property successfully cleaned up
User triggered an error while uploading a new property.
Error message: Upload Error: $thumbnailsPath is false and/or not a dir: ". Property ID: 200
```

That means `rollback()` was executed/ didn't return false but the tables were inserted anyways...

Now about the new php features since 5.4:

- 5.5 added the finally block, do I just use it for setting autocommit to true?
- I read php 7 improved the errors handling but I really have no idea how to take advantage of this.

I need this fixed because I wouldn't like my production db ending full of broken/unused data, who would?

Comment: Use `try`, `catch` and `finally` blocks that capture the `mysqli_sql_exception`. On exception do a rollback, you can also throw exceptions in the try block if you have data that you're not looking for.

Comment: I can't use finally I'm using php 5.4, is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Xorifelse mentioned, your best option is to use `try` and `catch` even if you can't use `finally`. I've never used `mysqli` but I am assuming it is similar to `PDO` where you would do something like this:

```
$redirect = false;

try {
    $mysqli = new mysqli(...);
    $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);

    // rollback should revert here
    $mysqli->begin_transaction();

    if ($stmt_one = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO main_table (one, two, three) VALUES (?, ?, ?)')) {
        $stmt_one->bind_param('sss', $one, $two, $three);
        if (!$stmt_one->execute()) {
            throw new Exception($stmt_one->error);
        }

        $id = (int) $mysqli->insert_id;

        if ($stmt_two = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO sub_table_one (id, four) VALUES (?, ?)')) {
            $stmt_two->bind_param('is', $id, $four);
            if (!$stmt_two->execute()) {
                throw new Exception($stmt_two->error);
            }
        }

        if ($stmt_three = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO sub_table_two (id, five) VALUES (?, ?)')) {
            $stmt_three->bind_param('is', $id, $five);
            if (!$stmt_three->execute()) {
                throw new Exception($stmt_three->error);
            }
        }
    }

    if ($mysqli->commit()) {
        $redirect = true;
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Transaction commit failed.');
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    try {
        // something went wrong, we have to rollback
        $mysqli->rollback();
        // and display the error message
        echo $e->getMessage();
    } catch (Exception $f) {
        // and display the error message
        echo $f->getMessage();
    }
}

// don't forget to do this also
$mysqli->autocommit(TRUE);

if ($redirect) {
    header('Location: /');
}
```

In regards to the last line,

> According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php#89976,
>   calling $mysqli->commit() will NOT automatically set autocommit() back
>   to 'true'. That means that any queries following $mysqli->commit() will
>   be rolled back when your script exits, if autocommit() will be not
>   switched back to TRUE.

Comment: Will the last line be executed with the header redirection?

Comment: I do not think so. I've edited my answer, so that it redirects after the last line.

Comment: And if you decide to upgrade to a newer version of PHP, the `header()` can be done in a finally block.

Comment: @Xorifelse Hi! I've upgraded to php 7 and I'm having problems with the rollback function (it doesn't return false but it doesn't rollback either). I've just upgraded my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Mikey Do you know why it's not working now with php 7?

Comment: Little bit confused. If it enters your `catch` block, `rollback()` should return `true` if it rolls back successfully. From what it looks like, it is returning `true` hence why you are not seeing `no rollback :(` in your log. However, the bigger issue is more so that it is returning `true` when it is not actually rolling back. One thing to note is that you can only do [transactions with InnoDB table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11972317/1022914). So check that your table is using a InnoDB storage engine. If the problem persist, I think it's better to post a new question.

Comment: So there's the rub :) when I installed kloxomr7 I forgot to change from the default engine (MyISAM) to InnoDB... Thanks again!